# Select based on other Select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need your help with an AngularJS issue: I would like to have a HTML `select` based on other HTML `select` (this is a very common web issue). I achieved this task this way:

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select data-ng-change="getOffices()" data-ng-model="selectedCustomer" data-ng-options="customer.name for customer in customers" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose customer...</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose office...</option>
        <option data-ng-repeat="office in selectedCustomer.offices.getAll">{{office.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("app").controller("receiptsController", ["$scope",
    function ($scope){

        //selected customer
        $scope.selectedCustomer = null;

        //get offices related to the selected customer
        $scope.getOffices = function(){
            if($scope.selectedCustomer !== null)
                $scope.selectedCustomer.getOffices();
        };
}]);
```

This works properly, but I would like to understand why the following solution doesn't work. Assuming the same controller, the view became:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select data-ng-change="getOffices()" data-ng-model="selectedCustomer" data-ng-options="customer.name for customer in customers" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose customer...</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" data-ng-options="office.name for office in selectedCustomer.offices.getAll">
        <option value="">Choose office...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In this case (using `data-ng-options` directive in both selects) the second `select` is not filled. Can someone explain me why? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** the method `getOffices()` is an AJAX request:

```
angular.module("app").factory("GetOffices", ["$resource", 
    function($resource){
        return $resource("../retrieveOffices.php",
        {customerID:'@id'});
}]);
```

Comment: can you post the code for `getOffices()` method as well ?

Comment: I edited the post writing the code of getOffices()

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this, see angular documentation on  $resource

```
 angular.module("app").controller("receiptsController", ["$scope",GetOffices
        function ($scope,GetOffices){

            //selected customer
            $scope.selectedCustomer = null;

            //get offices related to the selected customer
            $scope.getOffices = function(){
                if($scope.selectedCustomer !== null)
                    $scope.selectedCustomer=GetOffices.get({customerID:123});
            };
    }]);
```

Comment: I do that. In the getOffices() method there is an ajax call like yours.